# Multiple request in Angular2 RC1

Tags: angular

I have used async pipe in angular 2 RC1, which lead to multiple request to server.
In Angular2 beta 16 i have used share method to solve this.

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
```

In constructor am requesting `this._http.get(path, options)`

In beta version i was using `this._http.get(path, options).share()`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: In my constructor i use this.data = this._http.get(path, options); and in my html i use data | async which requests url two times please provide me solution.
I think you got my problem

Comment: No, I don't get the problem. Did `.share()` work in beta.16? Why don't you use it the same in RC1?

Comment: In RC1 .share() method does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
```